# Android Dynamically Created Button: setOnClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, button, onclick

The `onClick` never fires! Why not? Please help me.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    String title = "Button" + i;
    Button sliderButton = new Button(this);
    sliderButton.setText(title);
    glideMenuTray.addView(sliderButton,100,40);

    sliderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("gm", "Tapped ");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I doubt it will make any difference at all, but have you tried adding the `OnClickListener` before calling `glideMenuTray.addView()`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert at stuff like this, but it's probably something to do with garbage collection, and the OnClickListeners passing out of scope.

Though I don't think you can use the super-easy approach to onClickListeners that Dimitar mentions, you can probably use the middle approach that the section he links to discusses, even though it's not a new approach.  To repeat the example code here, it's:

```
View.OnClickListener handler = View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.myButton: // doStuff
                break;
            case R.id.myOtherButton: // doStuff
                break;
        }
    }
}

findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.myOtherButton).setOnClickListener(handler);
```

If the only thing distinguishing the buttons is their title text, well, you could use that to distinguish between them in the master onClick method.

Comment: Stuff is not garbage collected unless it is not reachable via any gc root. The OP's code creates buttons that are added to glideMenuTray which is presumably referenced by something (e.g. an Activity) which is reachable from a gc root and therefore the garbage collection argument makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Also, not shure, I once had a problem like that on a TextView and it was because I didnt add `setClickable(true)`

My code was something like

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
text.setText("***");
text.setClickable(true);

text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //My action
    }
});

myViewGroup.addView(text );
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Donut or Eclair, you can use common click listener, registered in your Activity and hooked with your buttons in the layout XML.

For reference, look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html), the category **Easier click listeners**.

Comment: I don't think that method for Easier click listeners will work, since his Buttons are dynamic, not pre-defined in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in assuming that the following line:

```
glideMenuTray.addView(sliderButton,100,40);
```

Adds the view to the coords x:100,y:40 onto some View extending ViewGroup?

In that case you are stacking 12 buttons on top of each other, only the last Button (labeled Button11) will be visible (and clickable).

And provided that the question is 3 years old I really hope you already resolved this by now :)

Answer (score 0):

**set the setOnClickListener before adding the view.**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    String title = "Button" + i;
    Button sliderButton = new Button(this);
    sliderButton.setText(title);
    sliderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("gm", "Tapped ");
        }
    glideMenuTray.addView(sliderButton,100,40);
}
```