# Increasing or Decreasing EditText value by 2 depending on which button is clicked, ANDROID

Tags: android

I've found alot of answers to do close things, but nothing has what I am looking for.  Been searching for an answer for several days.

I have a single TextEdit field named textEdit1.

I also have a button on each side of it, button1 and button10.

The initial value of the TextEdit field is 0 (set by a string I might add in case that makes a difference)

If I click button1, I need that value to decrease by 2.  If I click button10 I need that value to increase by 2.

This is a type of scoring application where - points are better then + points.  So I need ot be able to have this do negative values.

This is for Android, and it has ot be backwards comaptible so I'm building it on API 3.  I need it to be able to run on 1.5.

The following is my XML Code.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonYes" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/valueInitial" >

        </EditText>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonNo" />
```

Essentially, if the person in question has made progress you hit the "yes" button which is button1 and it subracts 2 points.  If they did not make progress, or the yes button was accidently pressed, you hit the "no" button which is buttong10, and it adds to points.

There are several sequential buttons like this with different point values for different situations.  Once it's all done, you hit a scoring button at the bottom and it does the math of all the EditText fields, and displays the final score.

In addition I don't want anyone to be able to tap on the EditText field and enter a value, I am unable to find this information either.  The value should only be able to be changed by hitting one of these two buttons.

Ok after some help I've got the following, it's close I'm sure, but I just don't have the experience in Android or Java, my experience is in VB.NET.  This is what I have so far, but am getting alot of errors.

```
public class ScoringActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setButtonClickListener();
}
public int progress;

    private void setButtonClickListener() {
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button10.setOnClickListener(this); {
            public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(v == button1){
                this.total -= 2;
                textEdit1.setText(String.valueOf(this.progress); 
                }
                if(v == button10){
                this.total += 2;
                textEdit1.setText(String.valueOf(this.progress);    
                }

                }

        });



}
}
```

It's not an imports issue as I'm not getting any errors like that.

Comment: It's core logic, put some code which show your efforts to get answer

Comment: Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653617/android-dynamically-created-button-setonclicklistener-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

well simple java

keep a class member veriable which keep tack of number in the edittext.

if click decrease

```
this.total -= 2;
TextEdit1.setText(String.valueOf(this.total));
```

if click increase

```
this.total += 2;
TextEdit1.setText(String.valueOf(this.total));
```

Comment: Riddhish: The reason I didn't post code in that I have tried is because I tried so many things and kept removing them if they did not work. I don't like to keep cluttered up code.  Mayank, that's the type of stuff I was looking for.  I understand the variable, as well as what that code does.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but for the "if click decrease" and it's counterpart, would be onClickHandler's for each button is that correct?  The only other question I have about that is, where it says "valueOf" is that something I have to chnage to match my situation or is that actually something builtin?

Comment: `String.valueOf()` is a built in function which returns String for given `Integer/Double/Long....` equal to `Integer.toString();` in your `OnClickListener` you can detect which button was clicked by comparing `buttonId` with `view.getID()`.

Comment: OK this is what I have now but it's throwingup a bunch of errors.

Comment: Not quite working, edited the above to reflect it.  I'm probably doing something wrong but I can FEEL it's close.

Comment: well you gotta do it like `if(v.getId() == button#.getId()) {` not `if(v == button)` that won't work

Comment: also what errors are you getting??

Comment: The two buttons under pribvate void, and both instances of textEdit1 in the if fields are getting cannot be resolved.  the buttons within the if statements are getting cannot resolve to a variable, which is fairly self explanatory.  Right above the TODO auto generated code the onClick says void is an invalid type for variable onClick.  Couple of syntax errors to delete the }); there at the end and the last two curly brackets in the entire code.  If I do that it goes nuts.

Comment: Now after making the if changes you suggested it's saying the buttons cannot be resolved. I know what it means that it can't resolve it, but it's kind of curious as to why it can't do so. The rest of the if statements seem to have cleaned up nicely now.  I also get what the code is doing now.  I got too spoiled by VB.NET and VS that's for sure. Wish they would have taught something like this instead, it's more useful overall I think.

Comment: you gotta post your logcat log, so i can see what errors you are actually getting.

Comment: That'sjust it I can't compile it to put it on the device.  Coming up with errors in the code itself.  I will get some screenshots if I can.

Comment: well that's why there is logcat and eclipse console which tells you what kind of compile errors you are having.

Comment: Here is a link to the screenshots hopefully it will work www.photobucket.com/michaelcodeimages

Comment: what I am looking in your code is lack of understanding of basic Java concepts. You have to go back and understand some basic Java concepts and how member variables are defined, how to attach listeners to objects and some other very basic stuff. Not trying to offend you or anything but without these basic concepts you'll have ton of troubles in your career.

Comment: No offense taken, but I've read and read and read the books and everything else and they've done nothing for me.  I don't learn well that way.  This is the way in which I learn.  Just like some people can read and retain forever, others need to be told others need to watch, others need to do, etc.  The bit you've done here with me has taught me more in the little bit of time I've spent on it, then reading the few books on Java code that I have.  Perhaps it's all in the presentation, I don't know.  I learned Vb.NEt and C# the same way. I could buildthis in either in 60 minutes or less.